# A question about Lebesgue measure and integration.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measurable space.
$f\colon X\to [0,\infty]$ measurable.

Denote $S=\lbrace x\in X : f(x)<1\rbrace$.

Prove

a. $\mu(S)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_S e^{-f^n}\,d\mu$

b. Assume $X=S$ , prove that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_X f^n\, d\mu= \int_{X} \frac{f}{1-f}\,d\mu$$

I have difficulty where I'm supposed to move between integrals.
We can define the measure in terms of integral. So in a I know that it is the start but it is not clear to me how to connect between the set $S$ to the integral.

In b, this is what I did:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_X f^n \,d\mu$= (by a theory int of sum =sum of int for a sequence of positive measurable functions)
=$\int_X (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^n)\, d\mu$=(sum of a geometry column with $f(x)<1$)= $\int_X \frac{f}{1-f}\, d\mu$.

Comment: what is your question? You solved part b) correctly, for a) note that $e^{-f(x)^n}\leqslant e^{-f(x)^{n+1}}\leqslant 1$ for all $n$ and all $x\in S$, therefore the monotone convergence theorem give you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For (a) -

We want to write $\mu(S)$ as the limit of some integrals... So it might be useful to write $\mu(S)$ as an integral. Of course, we know how to do this: $\mu(S) = \int_S 1 \mathrm{d}\mu$.

Notice this already looks kind of like the limit we're meant to compute. If we can show

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S e^{-f^n} \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_S 1 \mathrm{d} \mu$$

then we're done!

If you play around with this, you might notice $f^n \to 0$ pointwise on $S$ (since $0 \leq f(x) < 1$ for each $x \in S$). Then $e^{-f^n} \to e^{-0} = 1$.

So the stuff we're integrating limits to $1$, which is what we need it to be!

If only we knew how to relate the limit of a sequence of integrals to the integral of the limit of the integrands...

---

For (b) -

You're on the exact right track! Do you know how to justify the fact that $\sum \int \text{stuff} = \int \sum \text{stuff}$? Since infinite sums are simply *limits* of finite sums, you'll want to use the same technique of swapping limits and integrals from part (a).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yeah that really helped, can I use the monotone convergence theory this way:  $\int_E lim_{n\to \infty} f_n d\mu=\int_E 1 d\mu=\mu(E)$ since $e^{-f^n}$ is an increasing monotone measurable sequence (f is measurable and $e^{-x}:X \to [0,\infty]$ too) that converge to 1 as f gets values between 0 and 1?

Comment: @Almaa - You've got it!